# BeautifulSoup Python 2.7 Issue with loading a url from script

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib, attributeerror

This question pertains to a graded assignment. In the assignment I am asked to get a web-page, locate a html address, go to the address, locate another address, go to that address, and loop for n times. 
 I would like any insight to why my code is not loading a url. I want to understand what I am doing wrong, but not necessarily be given the answer.
 I am completely new to this, but quickly becoming obsessed.
I hope this question is appropriate in both form and scope for this forum.

The class requires Python 2.7, BeautifulSoup 3, and urllib,

> *MAIN QUESTION*: **Am I on the right path to think that the stored url in "url =" is the wrong 
>       type for urllib?**

Traceback points to lines in urllib.py that suggest it is not able to parse(unsure if this is the right word) lines 87, 185, and 1077 due to issues with object type.

I start with:

```
         url = ('http://some.known.website.html')
         # Then get web-page:
         html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
         # I use a "for" loop to iterate through the "tags":
         for tag in tags:
             # Then convert to string:
             urlname = str(tag)
             # Extract url with findall:
             url = re.findall('href="(http://.*)"',urlname)
             # load new "url" by looping back:
             html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

             # This is the contents of "url" (obfuscated) as printed 
             # to the terminal by a "print 'URL : ',url" staement:
             URL :  ['http://some.website.html']
```

This is the error message:

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "12-4test.py", line 17, in <module>
           html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
           return opener.open(url)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 185, in open
           fullurl = unwrap(toBytes(fullurl))
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1077, in unwrap
           url = url.strip()
      AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: it is hard to follow your code, copy actual snippet and make your comments comments.

Comment: First I would like to thank everyone who took the time to answer this question. I am going to try the suggestions and get back with results. I was reluctant  to post too much code due to it being a graded assignment.

Comment: Again I would like to express my extreme gratitude. Several areas of ambiguity have cleared away. Answers to questions I hadn't asked for that were lingering in the back of my mind. Realization is an interesting and rewarding process.

Answer (score 0):

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns list of strings with matches. You need to iterate over it in order to get actual url that you can pass to `urllib.urlopen`

```
urls = re.findall('href="(http://.*)"',urlname)
for url in urls:
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

or

```
pages = [urlib.urlopen(url).read() for url in urls]
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is that you don't need to use regular expressions to extract urls. `BeautifulSoup`'s [`Tag` objects allow a dictionary-like access to element attributes](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

```
for tag in tags:
    url = tag.get("href")
    print(url)
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I will try the  variations others have suggested. I noticed that in the terminal that url printed without square bracket or single quotes.